# Mobs die when there's more than 33~ in a 2x1 farm drop V1.11

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've made a classic mob farm using a zombie spawner in 1.11 and whenever I get 30+ mobs in my drop zone they just die when new ones come in, it's like they're crushing each other.

Is there any way to fix this? The water doesn't work, an extra drop layer using a piston doesn't work either.

Height doesn't matter, they die anyway if there's more than 30ish I Cant idle this way for XP anymore.

Comment: This is actually a new gamerule of 1.11. I'm not sure if we've found a way to fix this in vanilla mob farms other than to disable that gamerule

Answer (score 11):

*Suffocation* is a new game mechanic that was added in 1.11. From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.11#Gameplay):

- `maxEntityCramming`

  - Defaults to 24.
  - If one entity tries to push more than specified number of entities, it starts to suffocate.
  - Gets damaged 3 hearts by tick; passes though armor.
  - The death message is `<Player> squished too much`.
  - Setting to `0` disables the rule.
  - Affects all entities.

Basically, when there are more than 24 entities touching each other, and they can't move, they take damage. This essentially nerfs a lot of farms where lots of mobs are in the same area.

If you want to turn suffocation off, use the command (you will need cheats)

```
/gamerule maxEntityCramming 0
```

Comment: @GarlicDog you should make this "the answer". Please

Answer (score -2):

This is actually meant to be in the game it is not a bug, I think that it kind of sucks too but it is there.